# Graph API to set "send as" permission on Office 365 group mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-apps

I did try to research a lot but couldn't find it. I have to set "send as permission" for some users in an Office 365 group mailbox. I have an Office 365 group created and I need to assign the "send as" permission to some users in a group via API. I didn't find this information in the Microsoft documentation. Do we have any other way to make this automated?

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2022, this cannot yet be done through Microsoft Graph. Your only option for automation is to use Exchange PowerShell's [Add-RecipientPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-recipientpermission) cmdlet:

```
Add-RecipientPermission "Help Desk" -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee "Ayla Kol"
```